# gitlab ci to recognize volumes from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-delivery

I have a docker-compose file where I have all the environment necessary to run my test suite, and this docker-compose is the one that I use to run my tests on jenkins... However, now, I need to integrate my test suite on gitlab ci, but when I try to call my docker-compose from gitlab-ci yml, apparently the volumes that were supposed to be mounted on docker-compose are not mounted on gitlab-ci.

my docker-compose file:

```
[...]
  node-setup:
    image: jimador/docker-jdk-8-maven-node
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/front-testing
      - ./resources/downloads/:/app/front-testing/resources/downloads
    working_dir: /app/front-testing
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
      - chrome
      - firefox
    environment:
      - GRID=true
      - HEADLESS=$HEADLESS
      - BROWSER=$BROWSER
      - CURRENT_UID=$CURRENT_UID
      - TEST_COMMAND=$TEST_COMMAND
    command:
      - sh  
      - '-c'
      - npm install && npm run test; chown -R ${CURRENT_UID} target; chown -R ${CURRENT_UID} node_modules; echo Done!
    ports:
      - 7070:7070
```

my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker

stages:
  - run

run:
  stage: run
  before_script: 
    - chmod +x run-tests-docker.sh
    - chmod +x setup-tests-docker.sh
  services:
    - docker:dind    
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker-compose up
  only:
    - /feature\/.*/
    - develop
    - master
  tags:
    - gitlab-runner-docker01
  retry:
    max: 2
    when:
      - runner_system_failure
      - stuck_or_timeout_failure
```

the error that I'm getting:

```
[SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
node-setup_1    | npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/front-testing/package.json'
node-setup_1    | npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/front-testing/package.json'
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is happening? Does anyone know a workaround that I can do to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked `/app/front-testing/package.json` exists?

Comment: yes, it does.
that's why I think its a problem when mounting the volume, because despite the file does exists, it is not being found

Comment: Tyring using docker-compose image for CI instead of docker, like this:


 `image:
   name: docker/compose:1.24.1
   entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to that problem in a [GitLab forum post](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/docker-compose-not-mounting-volumes-in-main-gitlab-ci-container/21963): Basically volumes must be linked from resources inside of the project dir, i.e. inside of `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` in GitLab.